# Openshift Service Mesh ServiceMeshControlPlane deployment error

Tags: openshift, istio, servicemesh

I want to create ServiceMeshControlPlane but it can not be deployed as I see in logs below message:

```
Error processing component mesh-config: error:
mesh-config/templates/enable-mesh-permissive.yaml: Internal error
occurred: failed calling webhook "validation.istio.io": failed to call
webhook: Post
"https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=10s": service
"istiod" not found
```

All needed operators are installed succesfully: Jager/Kiali/ELasticsearch/Openshift ServiceMesh.

But on ServiceMeshControlPlane I receive this error, how to get rid of it?

1. Uninstall and reinstall of operators is not a fix.
2. Deleting istio-system namespace and creating one more time is not also a fix.
3. Creating SMCP on different namespace also ended up with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there were two not deleted ValidatingWebhookConfiguration, after manual deletion, SMCP can be created.